# Datasets for Call Centre Timeseries Forecasting

Tags: time-series, forecasting

Does anybody know of any open datasets that can be used for call centre analytics? Particularly I am interested in forecasting the number of incoming calls and also visualizing internal queues in terms of wait time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you http://klipfolio.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/81667-call-center-data-spreadsheet-

click on download.

Remember to account for Holidays(leads and lags), Day of the week patterns, seasonality, and of course outliers and changes in trend/seasonality.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Do you recommend an algorithm for forecasting that will take into account Holidays(leads and lags), Day of the week patterns, seasonality, and outliers? I was going to start with using ARIMA.

Comment: Yes, ours.  Click on my profile to see more.  Contact me and I can explain.  What we do is build a regression model at the daily level and include daily dummies, seasonal dummies, holidays and identify outliers (pulses, seasonal pulses, level shifts, changes in trend).  We take the forecast and history and use it as a causal which may not be kept in the model to model 24 separate regressions for the 23 hours of the day.  We call this mixed frequency modeling.  No one else does it that way that we know.  ARIMA is a poor man's tool for this type of a problem.  You ignore way way too much.

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for data as well - but its surprisingly hard to find good datasets. I recently come across the following site which contains a year's worth of data. http://ie.technion.ac.il/serveng/callcenterdata/index.html